# enable / disable CrossHaires by external button

Tags: highcharts

```
  tooltip: {
        crosshairs: [{
                        dashStyle: 'dash'
                    },{
                       dashStyle: 'dash'     
                    }]
                },
....

    $("#toggleCrossHaire").click(function(){
     if(chart.tooltip.crosshaires){
      chart.tooltip.crosshaires : [false,false];
    }eles{
      chart.tooltip.crosshaires : [true,true];
    }
    });
```

enable or disable and change dashStyle of Crosshairs . to solid and dash . by an external button??

this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/E568Q/2/) for more explication

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do here. Do you have a sample site up or maybe a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way:

- Get the current `dashstyle`
- Change it according to the style you want
- Force Highcharts to redraw

```
$("#toggle").click(function(){
    var options = chart.options;
    var dashStyle = options.tooltip.crosshairs[0].dashStyle == "Solid" ? "Dot" : "Solid";
    options.tooltip.crosshairs = [{
        dashStyle: dashStyle
    }, {
        dashStyle: dashStyle
    }]
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

[**demo1**](http://jsfiddle.net/c23Pc/)

Note that **the code abode works only for two crosshairs**.
If you want to do it with only one you have to create the chart and set `crosshairs` with the second disabled:

```
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: [{
        dashStyle: "Solid"
    }, false]
}
```

// remember to change the following line, because we just want to set the first one

```
options.tooltip.crosshairs = [{
    dashStyle: dashStyle
}]
```

[**demo2**](http://jsfiddle.net/c23Pc/1/)